# PHP GD Jpeg with a target filesize

Tags: php, gd

I'd like to feed PHP/GD an image resource and a target file size and have it output a JPEG file of that target size. Say, I have a 500KB PNG image that needs to be 100KB.

Example.

```
function target_image_filesize($im,$target_size){
  //create gd image
  //return a new image resource of specified size
}
```

I know I've seen a function for this floating around, and it's not something I'm looking to re-invent if possible.

Comment: You'd need to do it iteratively. build a jpeg. check filesize. if it's too large, repeat and reduce the quality setting.

Comment: +1 for very interesting question. But you didn't specify if the image dimensions are to be preserved or not. Only the JPEG quality can be manipulated?

Comment: Dimensions would stay the same. Only real goal of the function is to read the current file size of an image, if over limit, use GD to reduce the quality until the target file size is achieved. The output of the function (for my specific needs) would always be JPEG.

Comment: I have a solution, but this site has a weird policy about answering your own questions... so won't let me post it as an answer. I'll check back in a few hours to see if I can share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has this same problem, this should help.

```
function make_jpeg_target_size($file,$saveDir,$targetKB){
    $imageInfo = getimagesize($file);
    $filename = array_shift(explode('.',basename($file)));
    switch($imageInfo['mime']){
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
    }
    $target = $targetKB*1024;
    $start_q = 1;
    $cur_q = 99;
    while($cur_q > $start_q){
        $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'checksizer');
        $out = imagejpeg($src, $temp_file, $cur_q);
        $size = filesize($temp_file);
        if($size <= $target){
            $s = $targetKB.'kb';
            $saveAs = str_replace("//","/",$saveDir.'/'.$filename.'-'.$s.'.jpg');
            copy($temp_file, $saveAs);
            unlink($temp_file);
            $cur_q=0;
        }
        $cur_q=$cur_q-1;
    }
    if($saveAs == ''){
        return false;
    }else{
        return $saveAs;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, that's linear search along `$cur_q`. why not binary?

Answer (score 2):

The trick will be in specifying proper JPEG quality. But this parameter is never defined, [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-5.html) you can read that:

> In fact, quality scales aren't even standardized across JPEG programs.

But... there could be a clever solution! However a bit of work:

1) take few PNG images
2) convert them to JPEGs with with quality varying from (say) 50 to 100 by step 1
3) analyze the dependency between the quality and file size - is it quadratic:
`size ~ q * q`, or exponential - `size ~ x^q`, or reciprocal - `size ~ 1/q` or whatever..?
4) build a general expression to predict file size from quality and vice versa
5) post the result here :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the command line, I recommend to use http://www.imagemagick.org it is very fast. We use it in our similar application.
in php - system('convert ...'); 
or php lib http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

GD is quite slow and we had problems with it

Comment: how does this answer the question??? I.e. how you control the quality by spcifying file size?

Answer (score 0):

The filesize of a jpeg isn't just dependent on the save quality and resolution. If you have an image thats a solid color, and a photograph - they will be different file sizes because of how jpeg compression works. Unfortunately you'll have to generate it, test filesize, and then determine if you need to re-generate.