# Determine proper image quality for file size?

Tags: php, image, gd

I am currently resampling uploaded images to a static width and height.  I'd like to be able to create a new copy of the image at the greatest quality below a certain file-size threshold.  Currently, I'm using a very naive method - something like this:

```
$size = NULL;
$quality = 100;

while ($size === NULL || $size > MAX_SIZE) {
    // write the image to disk using $quality

    clearstatcache(TRUE, $image);
    $size = filesize($image);

    $quality -= 10;
}
```

Is there a better method for determining what quality I should use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP GD Jpeg with a target filesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015864/php-gd-jpeg-with-a-target-filesize)

Comment: @AlixAxel: If you read the answer to that question, you'd see that it's exactly what I've already posted and trying to avoid.

Comment: I don't think you are doing what Tomas suggests (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7016353/89771)... If I were you, I would prepare a few images, resize them with different qualities and use that data to plot a linear regression (https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Math.php#L546) - you could then use `m` and `b` (or their averages between several images) as your general expression to get a very good approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting file size depends not only on the quality parameter, but on the image itself. Generally, it is not possible to forecast the file size exactly.

You could make a series of measurements for your typical images and create some scale which would let you guess exact quality parameter more quickly.

You could also go for binary search which would converge at good enough point after some iterations.

Comment: I considered binary search, but decided that it would likely be more iterations than linear, due to the exponential decrease in file size from quality setting.  For example, going from 100 quality to 90 almost halves the average file size.  So, in most cases, 2 iterations of a linear search will be all that's needed, where a binary search would require 3-4 to arrive at the same conclusion.  I may end up trying to determine an approximate scale just from some randomly sampling, though.

Comment: well, at this number of iterations it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: For a standard search, I would have agreed 100%.  I think I was concerned with this case because I'm doing file I/O every iteration (and at the time I was considering dropping the quality by 1 every time instead of 10, but I've given up on that).  I guess this _is_ the only right answer.